# Chrome Android - Permission to use microphone denied

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webspeech-api

I use Web Speech API for a local website (look like 10.**.**.***)
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API

When I use the demo provided by google on my smartphone, it works very well:
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

But when I recover the sources of the demo to put it on my site (without changing anything) this does not work:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webplatform-samples/tree/master/webspeechdemo

**Moreover, there is written: Permission to use microphone denied**

**But no permission was asked (unlike the site demo of google)**

Do you have a solution? I completely block

This is version 60 of Google Chrome Android

Comment: It is because you are using `http://`.
You need to use security site, `https://`.

Comment: I think you need to install some files to access the speech recognition service. I am now finding out how that works.